# Ubuntu installer CAN detect Windows partitions while CANNOT detect existing Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, hard-drive

So this is my situation:

I have two drives, one is SSD with Win 10 installed on it, one is HDD with data stored on it.

I've made a USB installer for Ubuntu.

When I entered the step for detecting whether the computer has some other operating systems installed on it, I received "This computer has no detected operating systems", this is the screenshot:

[image]

And I also clicked "Something else" to verify whether the installer detected my Windows partitions. It turned out yes:

[image]

PS: I have tried "shutdown /s /t 0" command to full shutdown Win 10, it doesn't make any sense.

PPS: I have changed my Windows partitions recently using free partition tools, so I tried "fixparts" of Ubuntu, doesn't make sense too.

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you are wanting to install Ubuntu. Just because the machine states "This computer has no detected operating systems" doesn't mean GRUB won't be able to load them. The installer's partition editor is finicky, and gets confused when you have multiple partitions, or just randomly sometimes.

I'd install Ubuntu through the "Something else" menu you were in (these instructions are case specific, looking at the provided images):

1. Shrink /dev/sda2 by however large you want your Ubuntu partition. Having the main system on the SSD increase its speed dramatically. You can do it on the HDD, but the SSD is highly recommended. You currently have 12GB available, so I would at LEAST give Ubuntu 20GB. Looks like the Windows side is pretty full, so be mindful of your space.
2. Create a swap partition in that space, but only size it to how much memory you have (usually 4Gb is enough, which is 4096Mb).
3. Create an ext4 partition in the remaining space on the /dev/sda SSD for linux, mount at "/".
4. I'd suggest putting your home partition on that extra HDD drive, since it has a lot of free space, some not even being used. This is OPTIONAL: Create an ext4 partition in the freespace on /dev/sdb HDD for your home folders, mount at "/home".
5. If you didn't do the last step, you have 120GB's that aren't available on your HDD. I would either resize the partition on there to fill the area (which may take a while), or create another partition in that area for data storage: NTFS if you want it accessible by Windows and Ubuntu, ext4 if you just want it in Ubuntu. Mount it somewhere like "/mnt/Data".
6. Modify the /dev/sda2 drive, use as NTFS, DO NOT FORMAT, and mount at "/mnt/Windows". This allows you to access the Windows files from boot without needing to mount it manually.
7. Modify the /dev/sdb5 drive, use as NTFS, DO NOT FORMAT, and mount at "/mnt/Data" (or another name if you already used that). This does the same thing as step 6, but for the data partition.

There you have it! You just manually formatted your installation!

Comment: Thank you so much for your advices! Install Ubuntu together with Win 10 on SSD is a great idea. I've never thought about that... Since my Dell n5010 laptop has boot problems (I cannot choose whether to boot from SSD or HDD, only SSD is bootable), Installing Ubuntu on SSD also fixed this issue.

Comment: However, before I partition my Windows drives using free software "Partition Assistant" I can install Ubuntu together with Win 10 which means I received "This computer has Windows installed on it" at the same step I've mentioned in my questions. That time, I only installed Ubuntu on my HDD, while Dell n5010 just cannot boot from HDD, so I never entered GRUB (only GRUB rescue command line). I had to fix Windows loader to load Win 10 properly and give up install Ubuntu. Do you have ideas how that happens? I have saved logs from Ubuntu software "boot repair", if needed I can support the link.

Comment: You probably didn't boot to Ubuntu because your SSD was selected as the bootable drive in your BIOS. This means your computer looked at the SSD for an operating system, couldn't find one, and gave up. ___ You can load to GRUB by selecting the HDD partition in your BIOS menu. ___ The reason why your installation recognized Windows before you used Partition Assistant is most likely because after words, the installer couldn't understand the layout of the partitions (there was a big empty space, maybe). Thus, it couldn't reliably know there was a Windows partition. The installer is rather finicky.